# Authorization based on multiple scopes in C# web API ( scopes based authorization ) using policies

Tags: endpoint, claims-based-identity, asp.net-authorization, authorize-attribute

I am posting this to share information to Authorization in C# WEB API using multiple scopes.

After posting this user-defined I got a simple answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/4830196/ryan-wilson

Thank you [Ryan-Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4830196/ryan-wilson) for commenting your answer instead of just ignoring question.

i.e

```
options.AddPolicy("ReadPolicy", policy => {
       policy.RequireClaim("scope","scope1","scope2");
});
```

Authorizing based on a single scope I found reference from https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/apis/aspnetcore/authorization/

i.e in :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("read_access", policy =>
            policy.RequirementClaim("scope", "item1.read");
    });
```

and utilizing it at the end point:

```
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
    [Authorize(Policy="read_access")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return logic here
    }
}
```

The above only works for single scope i.e item1.read. If we want a logic to make the end point accessible with either of multiple scopes if have written following logic.

```
options.AddPolicy("ReadPolicy", policy => {
       policy.RequireAssertion(context => {
           return context.User.HasClaim(c =>
               (c.Type == "scope" &&
                  (c.Value.Contains("item.read") ||
                   c.Value.Contains("complete.read")   
                  )
             ));
         });
});
```

Here the scope **item1.read** means providing scope for only 1st item and scope **complete.read** means full access.

Hope this might helpful for any of us. Please hit like if this is understandable and useful. If not please share comment on how to improve my skills.

Thank you,

**Naveen Devi.**

Comment: Or you can just use the built in method: `RequireClaim(String, String[])` where `String[]` is an array of acceptable values or `public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicyBuilder RequireClaim (string claimType, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> allowedValues);` - [microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requireclaim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requireclaim?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are provided methods in .net that accomplish the same thing

Comment: Thanks Ryan Wilson, learnt an easy way.

Comment: I am new to StackOverFlow. Can you please check the below attached post, whether my answer is helpful or not.

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71927322/i-1-is-not-getting-the-last-element-of-a-list-javascript/71927746#71927746

Comment: I think you provided an answer and there is typically more than one way to accomplish something in the programming world. Keep it up.

Comment: Thank you Ryan Wilson.